# Deriving the constants $a,b$ from the solution to the Logistic Law of Population Growth

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am stuck at deriving the constants $a,b$ from the solution to the differential
equation *Logistic Law of Population Growth*,$\frac{dp}{dt} = ap -bp^2$ which is $p(t) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t-t_o)}}$ on problem $2a)$ from the book *Differential Equations and Their Applications*. 4th ed. on **page 37**.

The following is the question:

---

Choose $3$ times $t_o$, $t_1$, and $t_2$, with $t_1 - t_o = t_2 - t_1$. Show that $p(t) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t-t_o)}}$ determines  $a$ and $b$ uniquely in terms of $t_o$, $p(t_o)$, $t_1$, $p(t_1)$, $t_2$, and $p(t_2)$.

---

The following is my attempted solution:

---

From the solution to the differential equation *Logistic Law of Population Growth*:

\begin{equation}
p(t) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t-t_o)}}
\end{equation}

where $p_o$ denotes $p(t=0)$ while $a,b,p_o \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $a>b$.

By substituting $t_1$ and $t_2$ to the above equation respectively, one obtains $p(t_1)$ and $p(t_2)$ as:

\begin{equation}
p(t_1) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)}}\\
p(t_2) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t_2-t_o)}}
\end{equation}

Because $t_2 = 2t_1 - t_o$, the equation $t_2$ becomes:

\begin{equation}
p(t_2) = \frac{ap_o}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)}}
\end{equation}

Consider the equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{p(t_1)}{p(t_2)} = \frac{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)}}{bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)}}\\
\end{equation}

Rearranging the equation:

\begin{equation}
p(t_1)(bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)}) = p(t_2)(bp_o + (a-bp_o)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)})\\
p(t_1)(a-bp_o)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)} - p(t_2)(a-bp_o)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)} = p(t_2)bp_o - p(t_1)bp_o\\
p(t_1)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)} - p(t_2)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)} = \frac{p(t_2)bp_o - p(t_1)bp_o}{(a-bp_o)}\\
p(t_2)e^{-2a(t_1-t_o)} - p(t_1)e^{-a(t_1-t_o)} = \frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)}
\end{equation}

Let $u = e^{-a(t_1-t_o)}$.

It follows that:

\begin{equation}
p(t_2)u^2 - p(t_1)u = \frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)}
\end{equation}

The $LHS$ of the above equation can be re-expressed as:

\begin{equation}
p(t_2)u^2 - p(t_1)u + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2 - \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2
\end{equation}

which is equal to:

\begin{equation}
\left(\sqrt{p(t_2)}u -\left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)\right)^2 - \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2
\end{equation}

Hence,

\begin{equation}
\left(\sqrt{p(t_2)}u -\left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)\right)^2 - \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2 = \frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)}\\
\left(\sqrt{p(t_2)}u -\left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)\right)^2 = \frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2
\end{equation}

Taking the square root on both sides of the equation, one obtains:

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{p(t_2)}u -\left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2}\\
\sqrt{p(t_2)}u = \pm \sqrt{\frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)\\
u = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{p(t_2)}}\sqrt{\frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2p(t_2)} \right)\\
\end{equation}

Substituting $u$ back as $e^{-a(t_1-t_o)}$ to the above equation, one obtains:

\begin{equation}
e^{-a(t_1-t_o)} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{p(t_2)}}\sqrt{\frac{bp_o(p(t_1) - p(t_2))}{(a-bp_o)} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2\sqrt{p(t_2)}} \right)^2} + \left (\frac{p(t_1)}{2p(t_2)} \right)\\
\end{equation}

---

The above equation reminds me of a transcendental equation, but I do not know whether my derivation is correct or not.

Reference:

Braun, M., Golubitsky, M., Marsden, J., Jager, W. and Sirovich, L., 2013. *Differential Equations and Their Applications*. 4th ed. New York, NY: Springer, p.37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping that you do not mind, I shall change notations to make my writing simpler
$$P_i=p(t_i) \qquad p=p_0 \qquad t_1=t_0+\Delta \qquad t_2=t_0+2\Delta$$ So, the two equations write
$$P_1=\frac{a p}{bp + (a-bp)e^{-a \Delta } }\tag1$$
$$P_2=\frac{a p}{bp + (a-bp)e^{-2a \Delta } }\tag2$$

From $(1)$, extract $b$
$$b=\frac{a \left(p e^{a \Delta }-P_1\right)}{p P_1 \left(e^{a \Delta }-1\right)}\tag3$$ Plu this is $(2)$ which, after simplifications, write
$$P_2=\frac{p P_1 e^{a \Delta }}{p e^{a \Delta }+p-P_1}\tag 4$$ from which we can extract $e^{a \Delta }$.
$$e^{a \Delta }=\frac{P_2 (p-P_1)}{p (P_1-P_2)}\implies a=\frac 1 \Delta \log\Bigg[\frac{P_2 (p-P_1)}{p (P_1-P_2)} \Bigg]\tag 5$$ Plug $a$ in $(3)$ to get $b$.

Comment: Should not $(3)$ be $\frac{a(P_1 e^{-a\Delta}-p)}{pP_1 (e^{-a\Delta} -1)}$?

Comment: @Approxiz. In your expression, multiply top and bottom by $e^{a \Delta}$. It should be the same. Be sure that the solution has been verified. Cheers :-)